# Alterando Um Objeto Já Existente

Tags: javascript

Tudo Bom?

Estou tentando alterar um objeto já existente, inserindo novos valores no mesmo.

Ex:

```js
// Tenho um Objeto Values
let values = {
 customer: {
   name: "Fulana",
   address: {
     street: "Rua D"
   }
 }
}
```

Preciso de uma função onde eu possa passar este objeto, um path e um novo valor por parâmetro.
O path é o local onde eu quero guardar o meu novo valorlue(Ex: ["customer" "address", "number"])

No momento eu só tenho a função que vai gerar um objeto pra mim, mas não sei como fazer para alterar este objeto sem perder os valores já existentes

```js
//função para criar objeto

    changeObject(path, value){ // path = ["customer", "address", "number"] value = "34"
        let curr = value;
        for(let i=path.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
            let o = {};
            o[path[i]] = curr;
            curr = o;
        }
        return curr;
    }
```

```js
//Depois de passar pela função quero que retorne algo assim
values = {
 customer: {
   name: "Fulana",
   address: {
     street: "Rua D",
     number: 34,
   }
 }
}
```

Atualmente eu só tenho a função que gera o objeto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu costumo ter uma função na minha caixa de ferramentas parecida, mas costumo usa a API `fn('chave1.chave2.chave3', valor)`.

Para além de ser boa ideia passar o objeto como argumento (e cuidado com o facto de o objeto inicial fora da função, pois ele é alterado por referência!), precisas de usar `curr[key] = curr[key] || {}` para ele não sobrescrever somente o valor do sub-objeto, mas sim usá-lo se ele já existir.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
function changeObject(path, value, obj = {}) {
  const lastKey = path.pop();
  let curr = obj;
  for (let key of path) {
    curr = curr[key] || {};
  }
  curr[lastKey] = value;
  return obj;

}

let values = {
  customer: {
    name: "Fulana",
    address: {
      street: "Rua D"
    }
  }
}

const alterado = changeObject(["customer", "address", "number"], "34", values);
console.log(alterado);
```

Uma versão mais segura, onde o objeto inicial não é alterado podia ser assim:

```js
function changeObject(path, value, obj = {}) {
  const lastKey = path.pop();
  const changed = {...obj};
  let curr = changed;
  for (let key of path) {
    curr[key] = curr[key] ? {...curr[key]} : {};
    curr = curr[key];
  }
  curr[lastKey] = value;
  return changed;
}

let inicial = {
  customer: {
    name: "Fulana",
    address: {
      street: "Rua D"
    }
  }
}

const alterado = changeObject(["customer", "address", "number"], "34", inicial);
console.log(alterado);
console.log(inicial);
```

Comment: Vlw Sergio, Tu é brabo.

Tmj ;)